# How to fix 502 Bad Gateway Nginx?

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I get 502 when run my docker-compose

```
version: '4'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ~/.pg/pg_data/sch34nv:/var/posgresql/data
    env_file:
        - .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - backend_network
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    env_file:
        - .env
    networks:
      - backend_network
  django:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: .
    container_name: django
    image: django
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/apps/django/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/apps/django/mediafiles
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: >
      bash -c "cd /apps/django/ && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py migrate && gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 sch34nv.wsgi:application"
    networks:
      - backend_network
  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
      context: .
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/apps/django/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/apps/django/mediafiles
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"
      - "${NGINX_SSL_PORT}:443"
    networks:
      - backend_network

networks:
  backend_network:

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

```
FROM python:3.12.1

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt update && apt -qy install gcc libjpeg-dev libxslt-dev \
    libpq-dev libmariadb-dev libmariadb-dev-compat gettext cron openssh-client flake8 locales vim

RUN useradd -rms /bin/bash sch34nv_user && chmod 777 /opt /run

WORKDIR /apps/django

RUN mkdir /apps/django/staticfiles && mkdir /apps/django/mediafiles && chown -R sch34nv_user:sch34nv_user /apps/django && chmod 755 /apps/django

COPY --chown=sch34nv_user:sch34nv_user . /apps/django/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

USER sch34nv_user

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "sch34nv.wsgi:application"]
```

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default
COPY nginx/proxy_params /etc/nginx
COPY nginx/default /etc/nginx/conf.d/default
VOLUME /var/log/nginx/log
```

```
events {}
http {
    upstream django {
        server django:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name $HOST;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://django;
        }

        location /staticfiles/ {
            alias /apps/django/staticfiles/;
        }

        location /mediafiles/ {
            alias /apps/django/mediafiles/;
        }
    }
}
```

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
```

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OnAm.png)

I try to change nginx configuration, but it do not fix my problem. I try to check my log volume, but it`s empty.

> > curl localhost:8000
> > curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000 after 0 ms: Connection refused
> > but i use it outside my docker

> > curl http://sch34nvbot.ru

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Server Error (500)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Server Error (500)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

in chrome i get 502 and have not log in nginx

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 5.35.93.31:ssh          178.176.75.144:6400     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    316 5.35.93.31:ssh          178.176.75.144:10213    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 5.35.93.31:44294        5.35.93.31:http         TIME_WAIT
```

> > lsof -i -P -n | grep 80

```
sshd       91748            root    4u  IPv4 375880      0t0  TCP 5.35.93.31:22->178.176.75.144:10213 (ESTABLISHED)
docker-pr 111355            root    4u  IPv4 432088      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 111360            root    4u  IPv6 432093      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

> > lsof -i -P -n | grep 8000 - empty result